# How to test new TFS server without upgrading original

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have a TFS 2013 instance that requires upgrading.  I plan to use Azure DevOps 2019 on prem.  I'd like to have the two environments running at the same time so I can verify.  What I'd like to do is:

- Do full install of Azure DevOps server, creating new DBs on a new SQL server.  I do NOT want to upgrade our existing TFS at this point.
- Copy the data from the original TFS SQL instance to the new SQL instance, performing an upgrade along the way.
- Test and verify all data successfully migrated to 2019
- Schedule a blackout window and repeat the import process once again

Can anybody advise if this is do-able or refer me to a guide?

Tks

Comment: Did you look at the official documentation from Microsoft? You can find it with Google very easily.

Comment: All I found were articles on completing the upgrade in place, but once I began the config wizard, I see there's an option to do a pre-production upgrade built right in.  Tks

Answer (score 0):

Easier than I thought.  Just needed to run the pre-production upgrade wizard.